# JUnit test of a method does compile and shows multiple error markers

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am new to Unit testing and do not understand why the following code does not work. I have this method:

```
public class TaxTime {


public static void main(String[] args) {
   ...
}

public static double calculateFamilyTaxSaving(double taxAmount, int familyMembers) {
  for (int i = 0; i <= familyMembers; i++){
       taxAmount = taxAmount - 100;
   }
   return taxAmount;
 }
```

And I am trying to test the code with this testing class:

```
 import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;
 import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail;
 import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
 import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

 class TaxTimeTest {

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() throws Exception {
  }

  @Test
  void test() {
    fail("Not yet implemented");

}

@Test
static void stattestCalculateFamilyTaxSaving() {
    TaxTime taxtime = new TaxTime();
    double taxAmount = 600;
    int familyMembers = 3;
     assertTrue(taxtime.calculateFamilyTaxSaving(taxAmount,familyMembers).equals(200.0));
 }
}
```

Despite that the code does not compile and I get this message:

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> - Cannot invoke equals(double) on the primitive type double
> - The static method calculateFamilyTaxSaving(double, int) from the type TaxTime should be accessed in a static way

Could someome help me understand what I am doing wrong? I think I am missing something really essential.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I think that should be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot wrong with the code you included.
I'll start with some code then give some explanation.

```
public class TaxTime {
  public static double calculateFamilyTaxSaving(double taxAmount, int familyMembers) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= familyMembers; i++) {
         taxAmount = taxAmount - 100;
    }

    return taxAmount;
  }
}

public class TaxTimeTest {
  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() throws Exception {
    // only use this if you actually do some initialization before each test.
  }

  @Test
  void whatEverTestMethodNameYouWantToUse() {
    double actualDoubleResult;
    BigDecimal actualBigDecimalResult;
    BigDecimal expectedBigDecimal = new BigDecimal(300.0);
    TaxTime taxtime = new TaxTime();
    double taxAmount = 600;
    int familyMembers = 3;

    actualDoubleResult = taxtime.calculateFamilyTaxSaving(taxAmount,familyMembers);

    actualBigDecimalResult = new BigDecimal(actualDoubleResult);

    assertTrue(0 == expectedBigDecimal.compareTo(actualBigDecimalResult));
  }
}
```

Some explanation.

- Junit test classes (`@Test` annotation) must NEVER be static.
- Testing your code is made extra difficult because you are incorrectly representing currency as a floating point value (double in your case).
- Use `BigDecimal.compareTo` to double values.
- Pay attention to the code you write.  `600 - 100 - 100 - 100` is 300.  `600 - 100 - 100 - 100` will never equal 200.

Caveat: You are using JUnit 5.
I have almost no experience with Junit 5.
Everything I mentioned applies to a JUnit 4 test and should also apply to a JUnit 5 test.

Comment: To elaborate: Currency should not be represented as a floating point value (float or double) because they are not exact. One may not see it because the string representation is rounded.

Answer (score 2):

The primitive type `double` does not have an `equals` method. Additionally, `double` values are not exact (they are approximations) and should not compared with the `==` operator. Combining these two ideas, you can test `double` values in JUnit using:

```
assertEquals(200.0, Taxtime.calculateFamilyTaxSaving(taxAmount, familyMembers), 0.0001);
```

Note that JUnit considers the first parameter to be the expected, so the `200.0` literal (the expected value) should be used first.

The last value (`0.0001`) is a threshold. This states that as long as the first two values differ by less than or equal to the threshold, the first two values are considered equal. To be precise, the threshold is defined as:

```
threshold such that abs(value1 - value2) <= threshold
```

The resulting test case should be:

```
@Test
static void stattestCalculateFamilyTaxSaving() {
    TaxTime taxtime = new TaxTime();
    double taxAmount = 600;
    int familyMembers = 3;
    assertEquals(200.0, Taxtime.calculateFamilyTaxSavings(taxAmount, familyMembers), 0.0001);
}
```

---

Note that `Taxtime.calculateFamilyTaxSaving` is `static` and should be called in a `static` manner (use the class name not an object name).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but that does not compile either. I get "The method calculateFamilyTaxSaving(double, int) in the type TaxTime is not applicable for the arguments (double, double, int)"

Comment: @ffblord Make sure to include the closing parenthesis after the `calculateFamilyTaxSavings` method:  `assertEquals(200.0, Taxtime.calculateFamilyTaxSaving(taxAmount, familyMembers), 0.0001)`. I've updated the answer above to include the source code for the test case. Also note that `assertEquals` must be statically imported as well: `import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals`.